# Sticky child div changes its width when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I found this script from this [site](http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/). It creates a sticky sidebar.

In his example, he gave fixed values to widths. In my case, I used **percents**. Doing so, the 'sticker' width changes as I scroll down and changes back to it's (supposed to be) width when it hits back to the top.

My CSS version using percents:

```
div#sideBar 
{
    width:25%;
    padding:2.5%;
    margin-left:2%;
    float:left;
}
    .clear { 
    clear:both; 
}
div#sticker {
    padding:2%;
    margin:2% 0;
    background:#AAA;
    width:inherit;
}
.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

*Note:* I know this codes works with fixed widths. However, I want a responsive design that is why I used percents.

Comment: Was there some sort of problem you found with what you did?  Justify why this would be a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
 div#sticker {
    padding:2%;
    margin:2% 0;
    background:#AAA;
    width:20%;
```

Further explanation given below

"Even though certain characteristics are inherited automatically in CSS, there may be situations in which you want to increase the weight of the inherited property. Specifying a value of inherit for any CSS property that’s applied to an element **will cause the element to gain its parent’s computed value** for the property in question. By specifying in the author style sheet that a property should inherit its value, you can increase its weight."

Reference: [About Inherit](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/inherit-css-property-value/)